# Selecting g inside SVG tag in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, svg, d3.js

I have just started working in selenium and stuck at some point and need help from experts.

Here is my html

```
<div id='d3_tree'>
   <svg>
     <g transform="translate(20,50)>
        <g class='node'>
        </g> 
        <g class='node pe_node'>
        </g>
        <g class='node pe_node'>
        </g> 
     </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

I need to have all the `<g>` having class `pe_node` and invoke context menu on these `<g>`
I have tried to get the svg like this

```
node = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='d3_tree']/'svg']/g")
```

then I have read that svg can not be selected directly So I tried this

```
nodes = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='d3_tree']/*[name()='svg']/g")
```

and

```
  nodes = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='d3_tree']/*[local-name()='svg']/g")
```

But it is still not working for me and I am getting `[]` in result.

Can anyone guide me how to select the `<g>` with class pe_node inside svg

Any help  will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You were halfway there, the following should work:

```
nodes = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='d3_tree']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']")
```

Every element inside 'svg' has to be referenced as `/*[name()='']

In this case you can shorten it up a bit with:

```
nodes = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='d3_tree']/*/*[name()='g']")
```

Comment: This only selects the first `g` for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following xpath should work `//div[@id='d3_tree']//g[contains(@class, 'pe_node')]`

Comment: Thanks @cherya I have tried it but it is still returning [] brackets  :(

Comment: You can try to use css selector. If this classes are unique it will be like this: nodes = self.driver.find_elements(By.cssSelector(".node pe_node"));

Comment: I am using python lanuage and I am getting an error that AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'cssSelector

Comment: Try 'driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".node pe_node")' , but i am not sure about this :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you not select the `<svg>` element using the `tagName`?

```
node = driver.findElement(By.tagName("svg"))
otherNodes = node.findElements(By.Xpath("./g[contains(@class, 'pe_node')]")
```

Comment: thanks @Mark but that second line of code is not working for me :(

Comment: Sorry I didn't see before that you're using python bindings.

Try `node = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("svg")`
`nodes = node.find_element_by_xpath("./g[contains(@class, 'pe_node')]")`

Hopefully that will give you a list of the `pe_nodes`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,I am unaware of which language you are using.But the below selenium will might be helpful for you.Nodes will return all the elements under svg tag with having class as "node pe_node".

```
node = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='d3_tree']/svg]")
nodes = node.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//g[@class='node pe_node']")
```

Comment: Thanks @omkar I am using python language. I have tried your code but it is still not working :(

Comment: I am able to get node. but nodes is still []

Comment: not sure with how to write code in python but                    Nodes = node.findElements(By.Xpath("//g[@class='node pe_node']") should work for you.If not there may be other problem

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
//div[@id='d3_tree']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g' and @class='node pe_node']/*[name()='g'][2]
```